# "На похоронах" — ударение

Tags: орфоэпия, наращение

Привык к ударению на последний слог, и [Викисловарь](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B) даёт такое же ударение, но в "Семнадцати мгновениях весны" профессор Плейшнер говорит в 5-й серии в библиотеке Штирлицу (слегка вопросительным тоном, но уже делая вывод):

> — *Вы были на п**о**хоронах.*

И заодно ещё вопрос возник: *правильно я написал "в 5-й серии" с наращением или нет?*

Comment: Вероятно, авторы фильма захотели придать колорита речи этого персонажа.  Вспоминается постановка чеховской пьесы: "утром поищи в библиОтеке Батюшкова".

Comment: @Alex_ander: наверное. Спасибо за идею! А в слове "библиотека" раньше ж и было такое ударение (на О).

Comment: В телефильме начала 90-х "Прогулки с Бродским", увидев похороны (дело в Венеции происходит), Бродский говорит что-то вроде: "Не надо сейчас снимать, там похорОны".  Никто не знает - это просто ошибка или что-нибудь старо-питерское?

Answer (score 1):

Вот наш главный ориентир - [Русское словесное ударение](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8B):

> п**о**хороны, похор**о**н, -**а**м,-**а**ми [не п**о**хорон,
>   п**о**хоронам]
>
> ---
>
> Сон мне снится — вот те н**а**:
>
> Гроб среди квартиры,
>
> На мои похорон**а**
>
> Съехались вампиры.
>
> ---
>
> Стали речи говорить —
>
> Всё про долголетие,
>
> Кровь сосать решили погодить:
>
> Вкусное — на третье...

Наращение правильное, а что, хотелось с гласной начать? Так за это ж канделябром, угу.

Comment: Стиль ваших ответов совершенно неподражаем, я бы назвала его разговорно-художественным. Интересно, есть такой стиль в русском языке.

Comment: *...а что, хотелось с гласной начать? Так за это ж канделябром, угу.* — ))) Да нет, не с гласной, подумал, что, может, не нужно оно вообще (как, например в *5 июня*). Загуглил сочетание с наращением и без, и даже больше получилось без. Вот засомневался и спросил.

Comment: *Интересно, есть такой стиль в русском языке.* — Если и нету, то, чтобы характеризовать Галину, надо его придумать. =)

Comment: Спасибо, Тёмыч и Шаронушко. Тёме по делу: 5 июня отдыхает: у числа месяца не бывает наращений. Вот если б: *в июне, где-то 5-го...*